# React.js: How to pass onchange value of listbox to function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass value from the onchange of listbox to a function called `handleOnChange`

In the `handleOnChange` function, I set the value to state (array)

However, I get an error when I try to add curly braces when enclosing `selected`

Eventually, I will be trying to pass this as a json request

*ProfileMaintenancePage.js*

```
    const [selectedModules, setSelectedModules] = useState([]);

    const handleOnChange = (selected) => {
        console.log("selected " + selected)
        setSelectedModules(selected)
      };

    return (
    <DualListBox
        options={ newOptionsListbox }
        selected={ selectedModules }
        onChange={ handleOnChange }
        showHeaderLabels={ true }
        disabled={ disabled }
                />
    )
```

The value is passed correctly to the `handleOnChange`

Is this the correct way to set this on the state?

How can I access this from the state?

TIA

EDIT:

Full page code of ProfileMaintenancePage.js

```
import React, {useState, useCallback, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import { MDBCard, MDBCardBody, MDBBreadcrumb, MDBBreadcrumbItem, MDBDataTable, MDBCol, MDBBtn } from 'mdbreact';
import 'react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import filterFactory, { textFilter } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-filter';
import 'react-dual-listbox/lib/react-dual-listbox.css';
import DualListBox from 'react-dual-listbox';
import ProfileMaintenanceService from '../../services/ProfileMaintenanceService';

const ProfileMaintenancePage = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [listboxModules, setListboxModules] = useState([]); /* populate modules listbox */
  const [selectedModules, setSelectedModules] = useState([]); /* store selected modules */
  const [modulesIds, setModuleIds] = useState(''); /* store selected modules */

  const [listboxActions, setListboxActions] = useState([]); /* populate modules listbox */

  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const retrieveModulesList = useCallback(() => {
    ProfileMaintenanceService.retrieveModulesList()
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveModulesList response.data >>> " + response.data)
      console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveModulesList JSON.stringify(response.data) >>> " + JSON.stringify(response.data))
      setListboxModules(response.data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveModulesList catch >>> " + err)
    })
  });

  const retrieveActionsList = useCallback((selectedModules) => {
    ProfileMaintenanceService.retrieveActionsList(selectedModules)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveActionsList response.data >>> " + response.data)
      console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveActionsList JSON.stringify(response.data) >>> " + JSON.stringify(response.data))
      setListboxActions(response.data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveActionsList catch >>> " + err)
    })
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveModulesList();
  }, []);

  /* CLIENT */
  const columnsClient = [
    {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#a6a6a6'
    },
    dataField: 'name',
    text: 'Name',
    sort: true,
    filter: textFilter()
    }, 

    {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#a6a6a6'
    },
    dataField: 'creator',
    text: 'Creator',
    sort: true
    // filter: textFilter()
    }, 

    {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#a6a6a6'
    },
    dataField: 'creationdate',
    text: 'Creation Date',
    sort: true
    // filter: textFilter()
    }, 

    {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#a6a6a6'
    },
    dataField: 'lastmodifier',
    text: 'Last Modifier',
    sort: true
    // filter: textFilter()
    }, 

    {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#a6a6a6'
    },
    dataField: 'lastmodification',
    text: 'Last Modification',
    sort: true
    // filter: textFilter()
    }, 
  ];

  const selectRowClient = {
    mode: 'checkbox',
    clickToSelect: true,
    clickToEdit: false,
    hideSelectAll: false,
    hideSelectColumn: false,
    onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex) => {
    }
  };

  /* Pagination */
  const customTotal = (from, to, size) => (
    <span className="react-bootstrap-table-pagination-total">
      Showing { from } to { to } of { size } Results
    </span>
  );

  const options = {
    paginationSize: 4,
    pageStartIndex: 0,
    alwaysShowAllBtns: true, 
    hideSizePerPage: true,
    firstPageText: 'First',
    prePageText: 'Back',
    nextPageText: 'Next',
    lastPageText: 'Last',
    nextPageTitle: 'First page',
    prePageTitle: 'Pre page',
    firstPageTitle: 'Next page',
    lastPageTitle: 'Last page',
    showTotal: true,
    paginationTotalRenderer: customTotal,
    sizePerPageList: [{
      text: '5', value: 5
    }, {
      text: '10', value: 10
    }, {
      text: 'All', value: data.length
    }] 
  };
  /* CLIENT -- end */

  const newOptionsListbox = listboxModules.map(({id, module, description}) => ({
    id: id,
    label: module,
    value: id /* temporarily set to id but it should be description */
  }))

  const newOptionsListbox2 = listboxModules.map(({id, module, description}) => ({
    id: "",
    label: "",
    value: "" /* temporarily set to id but it should be description */
  }))

  const handleOnChange = (selected) => {
    console.log("selected " + selected)
    setSelectedModules( selected )
    // setModuleIds(selectedValues)
    retrieveActionsList()
  };

  const addProfile = () => {
    setDisabled(false);
  };

   return (
    <div>
    <MDBCard className="mb-2">
    <MDBCardBody id="breadcrumb" className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <MDBBreadcrumb>
        <MDBBreadcrumbItem>Administrator</MDBBreadcrumbItem>
        <MDBBreadcrumbItem active>Profile Maintenance</MDBBreadcrumbItem>
      </MDBBreadcrumb>
    </MDBCardBody>
    </MDBCard>
    <MDBCard className="mb-2">
      <MDBCardBody>
        <MDBCard className="mb-2">
          <MDBCardBody>
          <MDBCard className="mb-2">
            <MDBCardBody>
            <MDBCol md="12">
            <form className="form-horizontal form-group">
            <div className="text-left mt-2">
                <MDBBtn color="indigo" type="button" onClick={() => { addProfile(); }}>Add</MDBBtn>
                <MDBBtn color="indigo" type="button" onClick={() => {}}>Delete</MDBBtn>
            </div>
            </form>
            </MDBCol>
            <BootstrapTable
              keyField='id'
              hover
              data={ '' }
              columns={ columnsClient }
              filter={ filterFactory() }
              selectRow={ selectRowClient }
              noDataIndication="No record(s) found."
              pagination={ paginationFactory(options) }
            />
            </MDBCardBody>
            </MDBCard>
            <MDBCol md="6">
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="name" className="dark-grey-text">
                Name
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" className="form-control" 
                value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} disabled={disabled} />
            </MDBCol>
            <MDBCol md="12">
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="entities" className="dark-grey-text">
                Modules
            </label>
            <DualListBox
                options={ newOptionsListbox }
                selected={ selectedModules }
                onChange={ handleOnChange }
                showHeaderLabels={ true }
                disabled={ disabled }
            />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="entities" className="dark-grey-text">
                Actions
            </label>
            {/* <DualListBox
                options={ newOptionsListbox2 }
                selected={ selectedModules }
                onChange={ onChange }
                showHeaderLabels={ true }
                disabled={ disabled }
            /> */}
            <br />
            </MDBCol>
            <MDBCol md="12">
            <form className="form-horizontal form-group">
            <div className="text-right mt-2">
                <MDBBtn color="indigo" type="button" onClick={() => {}}>Export</MDBBtn>
                <MDBBtn color="indigo" type="button" onClick={() => {}}>Cancel</MDBBtn>
                <MDBBtn color="indigo" type="button" onClick={() => {}}>Save</MDBBtn>
            </div>
            </form>
            </MDBCol>
            </MDBCardBody>
          </MDBCard>
      </MDBCardBody>
    </MDBCard>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProfileMaintenancePage;
```

Issue:

When using this function, I can't seem to access the value of the state specifically `selectedModules`

```
const retrieveActionsList = useCallback((selectedModules) => {
    ProfileMaintenanceService.retrieveActionsList(selectedModules)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveActionsList response.data >>> " + response.data)
      console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveActionsList JSON.stringify(response.data) >>> " + JSON.stringify(response.data))
      setListboxActions(response.data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveActionsList catch >>> " + err)
    })
  });
```

Comment: what's the issue? seems correct

Comment: Share us full page code,we will be understand more clearly

Comment: The issue comes when I access the state using another function. Let me share the full page code.

Comment: Please see my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is an array in the state, but you always overwrite your array with one element.
So selectedModuels woud be `<DualListBox />` always.
If you want to push it, you could use:

```
newState = selectedModules.slice();
newState.push(selected);
setSelectedModules(newState);
```

Comment: Should I declare a new state?

Comment: I used slice() to create a copy of selctedModules which is temporarily saved in newState.
That the new module is pushed into the array and your "selectedModules" get's updated.

I'm not sure why you would need another state variable. What error do you get when you try to access the state?